# What is the meaning of `Position Fulfillment`?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I can't understand the meaning of `Position Fulfillment` in Human resource context.

Is it same as `Position History`?

an example:

[image: List of people,position and dates for a generic business]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you give us some context?

Comment: @Kevin I have just updated my question. Thank you :-)

Comment: Yeah, looks like you're right. It's a form of job history where the individual positions are listed for the people.

Comment: I suppose someone *might* call OP's list a *Position Fulfillment Report*, but I certainly don't think this would be "standard" terminology. I'm not really even convinced it's a proper use of the word "fulfillment" - just some HR worker's personal idea of how to make *"Report of Past and Present Positions **Filled** by Employee"* look more "professional". Presumably because they thought the standard title "Employment History" would imply "past employment within *other* organisations", and these look like "past positions within *our* company".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Position Fulfillment" is a term that refers to an HR employee's role in recruiting and placement. I was an HR manager for a while, and the list of people I hired or moved to new roles, including the dates of those roles, would comprise my position fulfillment list. Each instance of fulfillment includes a process of updating/creating job descriptions, placing advertisements, interviewing, checking references, and providing onboarding services for the new employee as well as exit interviews with employees as they leave positions. The list, then, is one of accomplishment for the HR employee.